# Python error message using QGIS "load them all" plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, load-them-all-plugin

I have many thousands of shapefiles organized into folders for residential neighborhoods (state/city/neighborhood).  I installed "load them all" plugin but get a python error message.

> An error has occured while executing Python code:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/realmarkable1/.qgis2/python/plugins\loadthemall\LoadThemAllDialog.py",
>   line 251, in load
>       self.apply()   File "C:/Users/realmarkable1/.qgis2/python/plugins\loadthemall\LoadThemAllDialog.py",
>   line 193, in apply
>       filterList )   File "C:/Users/realmarkable1/.qgis2/python/plugins\loadthemall\LoadFiles.py",
>   line 197, in **init**
>       bLayersOff, bDoNotEmpty, bSort, bReverseSort, numLayersToConfirm )   File
>   "C:/Users/realmarkable1/.qgis2/python/plugins\loadthemall\LoadFiles.py",
>   line 29, in **init**
>       self.tree = Tree( baseDir, False ) # Don't create a parent group   File
>   "C:/Users/realmarkable1/.qgis2/python/plugins\loadthemall\LoadFiles.py",
>   line 246, in **init**
>       self.root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot() AttributeError: 'QgsProject' object has no attribute 'layerTreeRoot'

Python version:
2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

QGIS version:
2.2.0-Valmiera Valmiera, c3a2817

Python path:

```
['C:/PROGRA~2/QGISVA~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\\processing', 'C:/PROGRA~2/QGISVA~1/apps/qgis/./python', u'C:/Users/realmarkable1/.qgis2/python', u'C:/Users/realmarkable1/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~2/QGISVA~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISVA~1\\bin\\python27.zip', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISVA~1\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISVA~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISVA~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISVA~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISVA~1\\bin', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISVA~1\\apps\\Python27', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISVA~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISVA~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISVA~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISVA~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISVA~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISVA~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win32.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISVA~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISVA~1\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins\\fTools\\tools', 'C:/Users/realmarkable1/Desktop']
```

Answer (score 4):

To use `Load Them All` you would need to upgrade your QGIS installation, because the plugin is using a method that was added in QGIS v2.4 (`layerTreeRoot()`). I suggest you to use v2.14 because it will be still maintained for several months from now.

If, for any reason (perhaps the IT department doesn't permit it or something) you cannot upgrade your QGIS version, try with the previous version of the plugin, i.e., [v2.3](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/loadthemall/version/2.3/download/), which was not using `layerTreeRoot()` yet. Let me know if you need help installing the plugin from a ZIP file.

*BTW, that's a very good way to post a question, including all the details.*